# Synchronize multiple audio and video tracks in Android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, vitamio

I have developed an iOS application that combines multiple video and audio streams playing simultaneously, using AVMutableComposition. The user can stream a video and control the volume of each audio track (bass, drums, guitar...)

I have been researching for hours and I cannot find a way of doing it in Android. Have tried with few MediaPlayer (but even in some devices as Nexus 5 they won't play simultaneously), ExoPlayer (but doesn't allow multiple audio tracks at the same time), Vitamio (cannot find a way of play multiple audio tracks simultaneosly), etc.

Does anyone knows how yo do it?

Thanks!